# Disable or block stopwatch (Javascript) when the tasks "Complete" or "Complete & Follow-up" or "Cancel"

Tags: acumatica

I just created the stopwatch on Tasks(ScreenID = EP404000) and when the tasks complete or complete & follow-up or cancel, every control on that screen should be disabled or blocked. But the stopwatch that I added, it still can click and enable.

You can download my Stopwatch project to public in Acumatica:
[here](https://github.com/phakying/Stopwatch)

[image]

Comment: if they are just PXButtons you need to enable/disable in Row Selected

Comment: It can't use JavaScript syntax in Row Selected.